# Generics and concrete implementations of strategy components

Tags: java, generics, strategy-pattern

I ran into a little snag with the concrete implementation of strategy components using generic types.

Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction with an example?

**Here is what I am working towards**, but I get caught up when I declare the decode method as it expcects a List when I create the ArrayList... Not a surprise.

```
public class CsvFormat<T,T1> implements FormatStrategy<T,T1> {


public CsvFormat(boolean header) {
    setHeader(header);

@Override
public final T decode(T1 csvData) {
    csvData = new ArrayList(); //ERROR**** 
    List<Map<String, String>> decodedData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(); //turn collection into an array of maps
    if (this.hasHeader()) {
        decodeDataWithHeader(csvData, decodedData);
    } else {
        decodeDataNoHeader(csvData, decodedData);
    }
    return decodedData;
}

 private void decodeDataNoHeader(List<String> csvData, List<Map<String, String>> records) {
    int recordCount = FIRST_IDX;
    List<String> fields = null; //= Arrays.asList(csvData.get(recordCount).split(DELIM)); //turn line into a list, first record
    for (String data : csvData) { //for each unformatted string
        int delimIndex = FIRST_IDX; //reset delim
        fields = Arrays.asList(data.split(DELIM));//after header, start mapping
        records.add(new LinkedHashMap<String, String>()); //make a new map
        recordCount++;
        for (String field : fields) {
            final String KEY_ID = "Column-" + (delimIndex + RECORD_BUFFER);
            records.get(records.size() - RECORD_BUFFER).put(KEY_ID, field);
            delimIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is what I had to start with** The only way I can think of so far to achieve the above without error is to overload the the decode methods based on what object they are passed..

```
public class CsvFormat implements FormatStrategy<
List<Map<String, String>>, List<String>> {


public CsvFormat(boolean header) {
    setHeader(header);
}


@Override
public final List<Map<String, String>> decode(List<String> csvData) {
    List<Map<String, String>> decodedData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(); //turn collection into an array of maps
    if (this.hasHeader()) {
        decodeDataWithHeader(csvData, decodedData);
    } else {
        decodeDataNoHeader(csvData, decodedData);
    }
    return decodedData;
}

private void decodeDataNoHeader(List<String> csvData, List<Map<String, String>> records) {
    int recordCount = FIRST_IDX;
    List<String> fields = null; //= Arrays.asList(csvData.get(recordCount).split(DELIM)); //turn line into a list, first record
    for (String data : csvData) { //for each unformatted string
        int delimIndex = FIRST_IDX; //reset delim
        fields = Arrays.asList(data.split(DELIM));//after header, start mapping
        records.add(new LinkedHashMap<String, String>()); //make a new map
        recordCount++;
        for (String field : fields) {
            final String KEY_ID = "Column-" + (delimIndex + RECORD_BUFFER);
            records.get(records.size() - RECORD_BUFFER).put(KEY_ID, field);
            delimIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the example you "started with" seems exactly right.  You have written a `decode` method that requires a `List<String>` as input, so it stands to reason that you would be implementing the `FormatStrategy` interface with that specific type as `T1`  and the same goes for the output type `T`.

Why would you do icky runtime inspection of the input and loads of unsafe casting when you can actually follow the pattern and create a new class for each specific concrete type you care about?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I would just implement more concrete classes from the FormatStrategy and work it out that way. Thanks, glad I asked before I ran off and started making a mess out of my code. I just didn't know how far I could run with these generic types, but now I do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written for decoding the data will always return a `List<Map<String, String>>` and can only work with a `List<String>` as input, so there is no reason for the `CsvFormat` class to have type parameters.  So what you started with seems correct, why aren't you satisfied with it?

Comment: I don't want to always pass a list of maps in to decode, so I guess the best way around that is make a separate object that implements the FormatStrategy in a different way. Thank you for the answer.